# SQL dealing every bit without run query repeatedly

Tags: sql

I have a column using bits to record status of every mission. The index of bits represents the number of mission while 1/0 indicates if this mission is successful and all bits are logically isolated although they are put together.

For instance:  1010 is stored in decimal means a user finished the 2nd and 4th mission successfully and the table looks like:

```
uid   status
a     1100
b     1111
c     1001
d     0100
e     0011
```

Now I need to calculate: for every mission, how many users passed this mission. E.g.: for mission1: it's 0+1+1+0+1 = 5 while for mission2, it's 0+1+0+0+1 = 2.

I can use a formula `FLOOR(status%POWER(10,n)/POWER(10,n-1))` to get the bit of every mission of every user, but actually this means I need to run my query by n times and now the status is 64-bit long...

Is there any elegant way to do this in one query? Any help is appreciated....

Comment: You should properly normalise your data into a table `uid, missionid, status` then it's a simple `SELECT missionid, SUM(status) FROM table GROUP BY missionid`

Comment: @Nick I agree with you. Is there function that can separate the status into an array of all bits? Then a join operation will implement the table  you mentioned

Comment: It's probably most easily done in your application layer. MySQL isn't very good at splitting strings.

Comment: @Nick I see.... Sorry I can only deal this output with SQL...

Comment: Agreed. And you might just as well store a bit wise integer

Comment: @Strawberry Got you.... I create a table store the integers like  `000...1`  `000...10` `000...100` ... Then a join can achieve the normalization mentioned by Nick. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: OK - that wasn't quite what I had in mind, but whatever works.

Comment: @Strawberry Wow, another way to do this? Can you please show more details...

Comment: Presumably, it's impossible for a user to submit data until every mission is attempted? So zero always means 'failed', as opposed to 'status unknown'

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious approach is to normalise your data:

```
uid mission status
a         1      0
a         2      0
a         3      1
a         4      1

b         1      1
b         2      1
b         3      1
b         4      1

c         1      1
c         2      0
c         3      0
c         4      1

d         1      0
d         2      0
d         3      1
d         4      0

e         1      1
e         2      1
e         3      0
e         4      0
```

Alternatively, you can store a bitwise integer (or just do what you're currently doing) and process the data in your application code (e.g. a bit of PHP)...

```
uid status
a     12
b     15
c      9
d      4
e      3

<?php

$input = 15; // value comes from a query

$missions = array(1,2,3,4); // not really necessary in this particular instance

for( $i=0; $i<4; $i++ ) {
    $intbit = pow(2,$i);
    if( $input & $intbit ) {
        echo $missions[$i] . ' ';
    }
}

?>

Outputs  '1 2 3 4'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the value to a string, remove the `'0'`s, and calculate the length.  Assuming that the value really is a `decimal`:

```
select length(replace(cast(status as char), '0', '')) as num_missions as num_missions
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=808bd8974d4d9d30c7134bd89ab3466a) is a db<>fiddle using MySQL.  Note that the conversion to a string might look a little different in Hive, but the idea is the same.

If it is stored as an integer, you can use the the [`bin()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_bin) function to convert an integer to a string.  This is supported in both Hive and MySQL (the original tags on the question).

Bit fiddling in databases is usually a bad idea and suggests a poor data model.  Your data should have one row per user and mission.  Attempts at optimizing by stuffing things into bits may work sometimes in some programming languages, but rarely in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. This is a good idea to calculate `How many mission a user finished.` But now I need to calculate `For every mission, how many users passed this mission` ...

Comment: @user2894829 . . . Actually, I'm not sure what this question is asking.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Be very clear by providing both sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do.  This question didn't define "passing rate", so I interpreted it (probably incorrectly) as the number of "1"s in each row.